# White Screen Error when using jsx file to create a GLB in my react three canvas

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Heres the issue, I have been reading documentation on how to use a glb file with react three and three.js to have a 3D model on my site.

The issue is every tutorial seems to work fine, but nothing is working on my end.

My "Intro" component calls the "Char" function from a Model.jsx file

```
import "./intro.scss"
import Char from '../model/Model'
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber"

export default function Intro() {
  return (
    <div className="intro" id="intro">
      <div className="left">
        <Canvas>
          <Char/>
        </Canvas>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <h2>Personal Site Test</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Model.jsx :

```
import React from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function Char(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/model.glb");
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group position={[0, 0, -0.2]}>
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat249}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_1.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat233}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_2.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat225}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_3.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat242}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_4.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat235}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_5.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat234}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_6.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat241}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_7.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat244}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_8.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat250}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_9.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat243}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_10.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat226}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_11.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat227}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cube002_12.geometry}
          material={materials.Voxel_mat228}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/model.glb");
```

This is getting its GLB information from my /public/model/model.glb (In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNKPR.png) I put an arrow to the three files I am talking about)

Here is also the error code from the react console that is not showing up in my terminal when working:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
chunk-7EZKCG2T.js:34 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
lct @ chunk-7EZKCG2T.js:34
2index.js:21 Uncaught Error: Could not load /model.glb: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)
    at index-212b30d8.esm.js:1613:1
    at _onError (GLTFLoader.js:61:1)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:82:1)
    at three.module.js:39938:1
react-reconciler.development.js:9747 The above error occurred in the <Char> component:

    at Char
    at Suspense
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1535:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3478:5)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
logCapturedError @ react-reconciler.development.js:9747
2react-three-fiber.esm.js:138 Uncaught Error: Could not load /model.glb: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)
    at index-212b30d8.esm.js:1613:1
    at _onError (GLTFLoader.js:61:1)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:82:1)
    at three.module.js:39938:1
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component:

    at Canvas (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3806:5)
    at div
    at div
    at Intro
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46:82)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught Error: Could not load /model.glb: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)
    at index-212b30d8.esm.js:1613:1
    at _onError (GLTFLoader.js:61:1)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:82:1)
    at three.module.js:39938:1
three.module.js:27169 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
```

[And here is a picture of how the site looks currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObiAe.png)

I have tried using gltf and obj files but none seem to work. I have tried many different methods including Suspense to hug the Char component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to solve the issue but it seems related to the 3D model itself rather than the code. I tried to import the glb file of the basic cube shape from Blender and it is working just fine...
Not sure what is wrong with it though...

**EDIT**: I think it is because the 3D model was composed of various objects. I joined every parts into one and now this is working.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same case! I got these errors (chrome and firefox):

```
Uncaught Error: Could not load /cube.gltf: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON) 
Uncaught Error: Could not load cube.gltf: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data)
```

So, I understood the problem is about the path of ".gltf" (or .glb).

Put your 3d model in "./public/" and not in "./src/" or even in root.

This short video shows how to create a new project that's working!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaRIHrRclVk&list=WL